# How to unwrap an callback in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook-login, option-type

I'm using FB Login for my app in Swift and when I make a graph request, it returns the following result:

```
Optional({
    email = "arjun.ramjams@gmail.com";
    id = 10218497873670001;
    name = "Arjun Ram";
})
```

Now, how should I read, each individual value(i.e: email, id and name)?

Comment: `func fetchProfile()
{
    
    let parameters = ["fields": "id,email, first_name, last_name"]
    
    GraphRequest(graphPath: "me",parameters: parameters).start{(connection, user, Err) in
    
        if Err != nil
        {
        
            print(Err!)
            
            return
        }
        
        let dic = user as! NSDictionary
        let userID = dic["id"] as! String
        let Email = dic["email"] as! String
        let fname = dic["first_name"] as! String
        let lname = dic["last_name"] as! String
        
    }
}`

Comment: If you can give this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func fetchProfile() {
        let parameters = ["fields": "id,email, first_name, last_name"]
        GraphRequest(graphPath: "me",parameters: parameters).start{(connection, user, Err) in
            if Err != nil {
                print(Err!)
                return

            }
            let dic = user as! NSDictionary
            let userID = dic["id"] as! String
            let Email = dic["email"] as! String
            let fname = dic["first_name"] as! String
            let lname = dic["last_name"] as! String

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `result` is a `Dictionary` of type `[String:Any]?`.

```
let result:[String:Any]? = [
    "email":"arjun.ramjams@gmail.com",
    "id" : 10218497873670001,
    "name":"Arjun Ram"
]
```

You can fetch the fields from `result` like,

```
let email = result?["email"] as? String
let id = result?["id"] as? Int
let name = result?["name"] as? String
```

Comment: I wish it was written more clearly. the 'result' has values that are already loaded into it, in your answer. I didn't know how to reconcile that with the 'result' that is thrown back by the GraphRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if let` or `guard let` for unwraping an object or variable
e.g.:

```
if let result = result as? [String: Any] { 
    print(result[“email”])
}
```

or

```
guard let result = result as? [String: Any] else {
    // return something
}
```

Comment: This is only answering one part of my question.

Comment: I’ve been updating my answer